# Firebase Hosting: gifs are not loading

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-hosting, namecheap

For whatever reason the gifs & pngs on my site for a friend are not working and I cant seem to figure out why. If you take a look: https://saadmetla.com/portfolios/3d-gif.html There are no relative path problems because its the same location as many of the other images.

Only jpg images are loading successfully. Are there any direct reasons for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the GIFs uploaded to your site are empty or corrupt.

For example, downloading
https://saadmetla.com/assets/Website/gifs/conway2.gif and opening it locally in Firefox shows me a "cannot be displayed because it contains errors" message.